# click to add selected radio text in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i add selected radio text to add in other div after clicked button using jquery.

I have created this [**Codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/LGLrBo)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="checkedWrap"></div>
   <div class="checkList">
      <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked" class="lbl"></label>TExt 1
  </div>
  <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked1" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked1" class="lbl"></label>fdsaf asdfasd fasdf
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="unchecked_disabled" class="cbx hidden" disabled/>
    <label for="unchecked_disabled" class="lbl">fdsafasf</label>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Click">Click ok to add checked radio text from the red div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "from the red div"   or  "to the red div" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly attach a `click` event to your `button`, then get the selected input radio using `:checked` selector and finally get the text from the parent using `parent().text()`, check the example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.Click', function(){
      var checked_radio_text = $('input[name=checkit]:checked').parent().text();
      $('.checkedWrap').text(checked_radio_text);
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
   width:400px;
   height:auto;
   box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 13px 13px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 13px 13px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 13px 13px 0;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:10px;
}
.checkedWrap {
   width:100%;
   float:left;
   padding:15px;
   background-color:#b71c1c;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
.checkList {
   width:100%;
   padding:10px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   float:left;
}

.lbl {
   float:left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 44px;
  background: #898989;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  
}

.lbl:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -3px;
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.lbl:active:after { transform: scale(1.15, 0.85); }

.cbx:checked ~ label { background: #6fbeb5; }

.cbx:checked ~ label:after {
  left: 20px;
  background: #179588;
}

.cbx:disabled ~ label {
  background: #d5d5d5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cbx:disabled ~ label:after { background: #bcbdbc; }

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.demo { 
   margin-bottom: 40px; 
   width:100%; 
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:5px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   text-indent:10px;
}

.hidden { display: none; }

.Click {
   float:left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height:30px;
   background-color:#0288d1;
   color:#ffffff;
   width:100%;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:30px;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="checkedWrap"></div>
   <div class="checkList">
      <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked" class="lbl"></label>TExt 1
  </div>
  <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked1" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked1" class="lbl"></label>fdsaf asdfasd fasdf
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="unchecked_disabled" class="cbx hidden" disabled/>
    <label for="unchecked_disabled" class="lbl">fdsafasf</label>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Click">Click ok to add checked radio text from the red div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code selects the text of the label you have currently selected and inserts it to the top red box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on( "click",".Click",function(){
         var text = $("input[name=checkit]:checked").parent().find("span").text();
         $(".checkedWrap").text(text);
    });
});
```

Also wrap the plain text into a `<span>`, it makes the code clearer and easier to select from.

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/rm4h0hw5/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=checkit]').change(function () {
    jQuery('.checkedWrap').text($('input[name=checkit]:checked').parent().text());
   });
});
```